# Error expression does not produce a value

Tags: vb.net

Hi I`m trying to program a voice controlled Internet browser in VB 2010 express and  for the first two commands  the code works fine but any other commands keep giving the same error. That being   Expression does not produce a value.

Here is a sample of the code and keep in mind i have buttons to click that activate the same commands and all of them work.

```
    Select Case e.Result.Text

        Case "Go forward."
            Dim SAPI
            SAPI = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
            SAPI.Speak("Yes Sir.")
            SAPI = WebBrowser.GoForward()

        Case "Go back."
            Dim SAPI
            SAPI = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
            SAPI.Speak("Yes Sir.")
            SAPI = WebBrowser.GoBack()

        Case "Navigate search ."
            Dim SAPI
            SAPI = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
            SAPI.Speak("Yes Sir.")
            SAPI = WebBrowser.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)

        Case "Refresh page."
            Dim SAPI
            SAPI = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
            SAPI.Speak("Yes Sir.")
            SAPI = WebBrowser.Refresh()

        Case "Go home."
            Dim SAPI
            SAPI = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
            SAPI.Speak("Yes Sir.")
            SAPI = WebBrowser.GoHome()

    End Select
```

The  bottom three  case`s all have the same error in the WebBrowser line any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure if you got to 'Navigate Search', and because it didn't work you stopped, but maybe it's because you have a space in there? I don't know?

Comment: Although it is not explicitly intended for this case, enabling `Option Strict` may help you catch errors like this before execution.

Comment: @JustinRyan, `Option Strict` have nothing to do with this kind exception. This exception will be throw by compiler while building, unless you continue even compiler found some errors

Comment: @Fabio This is true, however it would prevent assigning both `CreateObject()` and the result of WebBrowser.Whatever to the same variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all of the `WebBrowser` methods you are using (specifically the latter three) have return values. The first two return a Boolean (like a Function return); the rest have no return (like a Sub) and therefore can not be assigned to a variable (`SAPI`).

Have a look at their respective MSDN documentaions to determine how to handle each. In those cases where the method does not return a value, simply call it without trying to assign its result.

```
WebBrowser.Navigate(URL)
'instead of:
var = WebBrowser.Navigate(URL) 'incorrect
```