# Error : Expression does not produce a value

Tags: .net, vb.net

When I am trying to connect with a component, I get this error:

> Expression does not produce a value.

Code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Sub DevComponents()
        Using DevComponents.DotNetBar()

        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error expression does not produce a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701195/error-expression-does-not-produce-a-value)

Comment: It's using your sub as DevComponents, rather than what i'm guessing is your class.

Comment: You need to *create a new object* using the `New` operator. This should have been covered in whatever tutorial you're using to learn VB.NET.

Comment: Would it be possible to update and give us a little more of where you got this code and what you are trying to achieve? I don't use this but it might be you're after inheriting a component within `DevComponents.DotNetBar()`

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Your [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) directive expects an object. Whatever `DotNetBar()` returns, it isn't an object. Here's an example:

```
Using resource As New resourceType   
    ' Insert code to work with resource.  
End Using
```

Comment: Without more code, there's not much more I can say here - if OP updates their code with some more context, I can elaborate further.